# Ultimaker 2 Go - Converting to Use 1.75 mm Filament

Tags: extruder, hotend, e3d-v6, ultimaker-2

I'm working on converting an Ultimaker 2 Go to use 1.75 mm filament. So far, I have replaced the bowden tube, replaced the feeder with this one: https://www.youmagine.com/designs/alternative-feeder-1-75mm-version#information, and changed slicer/machine settings.

An issue I am having is grinding at regular intervals, causing severe inconsistent extrusion. Messing with the feeder tension does not do anything. So, I am wondering if upgrading the hotend to an e3D V6 will solve it. Is there anything else to consider?
[image]
I also wonder if the problem has to do with the knurled drivegear. Would this work fine with 1.75 mm filament?

[image]

`

Comment: To be clear, you still use a 2.85 mm hotend with 1.75 mm filament?

Comment: Yes. It worked well for Adafruit, but I would think using a hotend with the "wrong" filament diameter would not be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out a while ago, but I thought I might as well update this.

So the issue was simply there was not enough tension, and that pretty much solved all the problems. I also did end up using an E3D v6 1.75 mm hotend.

Right now, I'm working on making it print faster. I am using klipper on a Raspberry Pi Zero W, and I'm playing with different fan ducts to improve part cooling.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post your answer, I've upvoted to prevent the question to pop up once in a while (and the answer answers the question!). Mayby you can post a question (and an answer) on your Klipper adventures in the hear future, we really need some people with Klipper knowledge.